# How to get jekyll to copy sub folder?

Tags: jekyll

I have an imgs subfolder in my _posts folder for jekyll.  I link to images in that folder using the Markdown form:

```
![myimg](imgs/myimage.jpg)
```

When I generate the website, jekyll correctly creates the link:

```
<img src='imgs/myimage.jpg>
```

but it doesn't copy over the imgs folder with the image to the correct subdirectory in _site.

If the html is created as

> _site/2013/10/myEntry.html

the image should be in the

> _site/2013/10/imgs

folder for the link to work.

How can I configure jekyll to copy over the imgs folder to the correct place in the _site?

Comment: Just FYI -- the answer below will work fine, I think -- Jekyll only copies folders *without* preceding underscores, and only processes things in _posts with front matter. This is why it wasn't copying your images.

Comment: The plugin does work but thanks for the heads up about it only processing front matter. I'm sure I would have gone nuts figuring that out at some other point.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is best to put your images folder at the root of your Jekyll site, you can make use of a plugin that will make Jekyll recognize your images folder inside `_posts`. Prefix your image files with the same date format as what you use for your posts and they'll be copied over to `_site` in the directory structure you want.

```rb
# _plugins/post_images.rb
module Jekyll
  POST_IMAGES_DIR = '_posts/imgs'
  DEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'imgs'

  class PostImageFile < StaticFile
    def destination(dest)
      name_bits = @name.split('-', 4)
      date_dir = ''
      date_dir += "#{name_bits.shift}/" if name_bits.first.to_i > 0
      date_dir += "#{name_bits.shift}/" if name_bits.first.to_i > 0
      date_dir += "#{name_bits.shift}/" if name_bits.first.to_i > 0
      File.join(dest, date_dir + DEST_IMAGES_DIR, name_bits.join('-'))
    end
  end

  class PostImagesGenerator < Generator
    def generate(site)
      # Check for the images directory inside the posts directory.
      return unless File.exists?(POST_IMAGES_DIR)

      post_images = []

      # Process each image.
      Dir.foreach(POST_IMAGES_DIR) do |entry|
        if entry != '.' && entry != '..'
          site.static_files << PostImageFile.new(site, site.source, POST_IMAGES_DIR, entry)
          post_images << entry.gsub(File.extname(entry), '')
        end
      end

      # Remove images considered to be "actual" posts from the posts array.
      site.posts.each do |post|
        if post_images.include?(post.id[1..-1].gsub('/', '-'))
          site.posts.delete(post)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I know that's the default method but I want to keep my images with my text so they don't get orphaned (as has happened over the years with my MT and Wordpress blogs).  Is there no way to have Jekyll copy other content from within or beneath the _posts folder?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a plugin that will copy images within the _posts folder.

Comment: Thanks for the plugin.  It works!  But, I need the imgs folder to end up as a sub directory of the directory containing the final html .  I respectfully disagree that the 'best' place for images in a massive common folder at the root rather than nicely with the html that requires it.  I've updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Ah, I've modified my answer with a revised plugin to support that directory structure. You will need to prefix each image file with the same date format you use for your posts.

Comment: Excellent!  I had to change the File.join to `File.join(dest, date_dir + DEST_IMAGES_DIR, @name)` because the link will include the date so I won't want it removed ... and had to add `post_images = ''` because of an 'undefined local variable' error but otherwise it works as is.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :) Looks like I accidentally removed the `post_images` variable declaration when I was cleaning up my debug code before pasting it here. I've edited my answer to include that missing declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a Jekyll plugin that helps keep posts assets alongside the Markdown file, it might fill your needs: https://nhoizey.github.io/jekyll_post_files/

Comment: It means you still need to specify the folder in your Markdown, one of the things I wanted to simplify for the author, but I understand your own need.