# Include image in Jekyll markdown collection

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I created a custom collection in my Jekyll configuration:

```
collections:
  tutorials:
    output: true
    permalink: /tutorials/:path/
```

I have a markdown file with the path: `_tutorial/category/ios.md`
I also have an image with the path: `_tutorial/category/xcode.png`

In **ios.md** I use:
`![xcode](xcode.png)`

Which should make sense since they are on the same directory.

In the **_site** generated folder, I see

```
tutorial/
  category/
    xcode.png
    ios/
      index.html
```

So obviously the generated HTML is looking at the wrong place for the image since they are no longer in the same directory.

I thought of changing my structure to have my markdown file be `_tutorial/category/ios/index.md`, however all it did was create a folder called `index` so the problem is the same.

What is the expected way to include images in Jekyll/Markdown?

Am I supposed to keep them all in a folder at the root of the site? That would obviously work but it makes it hard to keep track of which images are associated with each post...

Comment: Does it work if you have ios.md and ios/xcode.png?

Comment: Good idea, seems to work. A bit counterintuitive, nor natural... My other workaround is to use `![xcode](../xcode.png)`.  But I am wondering what's the best practice too.

Comment: The best practice is most likely keeping images in one /assets folder as mentioned in the docs. You can organize your site in a way that makes sense to you. I have images in the same folders as their pages, and I haven't run into this problem because I use .html pages (Jekyll doesn't auto-create the folder + index.html for nice links in that case).

Comment: Can I write markdown in file with .html extensions?

Comment: Probably... in your layout you could do `{{ content | markdownify }}`. I haven't tried this.

Comment: @NathanH Jekyll cannot do this, but Hugo can http://stackoverflow.com/q/31012496

Comment: I found another workaround, change the output path to be a html file instead of a folder.

Comment: Is someone interested in writing an answer summarizing the above? I went with my last comment as a solution (generate .html files instead of folders).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your collection has a permalink ending with a slash:

```
permalink: /tutorials/:path/
```

Jekyll will turn your Markdown file into an `index.html` file to make the link pretty. So `ios.md` becomes `ios/index.html`.

You can dodge this issue entirely by using links with extensions. This is [the default option](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#step-3-optionally-render-your-collections-documents-into-independent-files). Note there's no trailing slash:

```
permalink: /tutorials/:path
```

---

If you still want extension-free links, then for the relative image paths to work, you can either move the Markdown up one directory:

```
ios.md
ios/
  xcode.png
```

or change the image path to `![xcode](../xcode.png)`. Both approaches seem counter-intuitive.